# Concatenate String Constant with auto incremented integer and store in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, development-environment

I want to Store something like this in userID of `Database(DDN00000001,DDN00000002,DDN00000003 and so on , as user ID)`

How to concatenate the string in front of integer and store in database.

Comment: first normal form suggest you dont want to concatenate, but there is to little information to say

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert integer identifiers to this form in PHP, before sending it to the database, you can use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```php
$user_id = 1;
$padded_user_id = 'DDN' . str_pad ($user_id, 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```